# Mediawiki Math Extension it does work from the command line, but not from PHP

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have moved Mediawiki from old server (LINUX) to new server(LINUX). Once i have moved Math functions are not working. So i requested IT team to install the relevant software and package. When I was trying to run in command line its generating math png's. But at the same time its not working in PHP.

Below command executed in command line:

```
texvc /apps/xray/data/apache_xray/docs/xray-wiki/images/tmp \ 
      /apps/xray/data/apache_xray/docs/xray-wiki/math "\alpha^2+\beta^2=1"
```

Localsettings.php

```
$wgMathPath         = "{$wgUploadPath}/math"
$wgMathDirectory    = "/apps/xray/data/apache_xray/docs/xray-wiki/images/math"
$wgTmpDirectory     = "/apps/xray/data/apache_xray/docs/xray-wiki/images/tmp"
```

Comment: Is it the same user in both cases? They might have different permissions.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has different configuration files (`php.ini`) for command line and apache. This might be the cause of the difference between the behaviours.